# What do the [], <>, - and -- mean in the help docs?

Tags: git, manual

What do the `[]`, `<>`, `-` and `--` mean in the help docs?

When I use git, I can use `git help` to show the usage of a command, but I am not quite sure I understand the symbols:

```
$ git help 
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

---

**EDIT**

Is there any difference between `-` and `--`?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/7/man-pages in particular the SYNOPSIS description.

Comment: Conventionally, single dashes are used before single-character option arguments, while double dashes are used before option names which are spelled out in full.  So notice the difference between the synonyms `-p` with a single dash and `--paginate` with a double dash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[]` means it is optional

`--` or `-` is actually to be written in front of the option. Some options start with a `-`, some with doubled `--`, stick with the one that is written for the option you need.

`<>` stands for some placeholder to be replaced by what you need. (e.g. `<path>` is supposed to be replaced by actual path of some relevant file for the option)

`[A | B]` means you can choose between A or B

---

NB : It is very much like the syntax of many Unix / Linux command line utilities "usage help". You can have a look at https://linux.die.net/man/7/man-pages, thanks @tripleee for the link.

---

Historically, there are several reasons why there are some options with only one dash `-`and some with two. Often, the "One-dash" is for an option where you use only **one letter**. But it is sometimes a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: What kind of "syntax" is this?

Comment: I think it's supposed to mean "syntactic conventions in manual pages".